# Distributing Values Over Time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In this example, I have two columns of data: Date and Quantity.

Example:
(See Screenshot Link)

What I'd like to be able to do, **with an excel formula** (if possible), is 'level load' these quantities and spread them out, as evenly as possible, over the given time frame while preserving whole numbers.  The ideal day of each value would correspond to Thursday of the given week.

Desired result:
(See Screenshot Link)

[image]

Comment: I assume if you had 6 in July that both the 21 and 28th would be 2?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: You are going to find that this is a bit too much for a formula to do.  vba would be the best method.  But I love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Any solution suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: @ScottCraner, you might find the answer below interesting....Your comment is still valid since it's been a stretch but I couldn't help myself taking on your comment as an intellectual challenge.

Comment: I'm a bit of a novice.  How do I accept it?  Thanks so much! @MayukhBhattacharya

Comment: I have another wrinkle I'd like to pose in here.  Along with a date and Quantity, I now have an 'item' column that'd I'd like associated with the dates and now spread out quantities.  @JvdV

Should I generate a new post to ask this question with a link to this?  Thanks for any feedback!!

Comment: @HelpMeCode, new questions get new posts indeed. If your current question has been answered, please consider to click the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: @JvdV I would love to, but unfortunately need 15 reputation points in order to up-vote or 'accept' your answer.

Error I receive when attempting to accept: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your
feedback has been recorded."

Comment: @helpmecode. Voting is different to accepting an answer. Next to the arrows to vote is a checkmark you can click

Comment: Oh, wow!  I feel stupid now.  I have accepted your answer!

Comment: @JvdV how would you do this in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, yet tough. Here is my two cents (and I might have been overthinking this by a mile):

- Assuming access to the newest BETA-functions (or an alternative mentioned further down);
- Months follow one another in order e.g.: may > june > july etc.

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=LET(A,SEQUENCE(EOMONTH(A5,0)-A3,,A3),B,FILTER(A,(WEEKDAY(A)=5)*((DAY(A)/7)-0.1<VLOOKUP(A,A3:B5,2))),C,BYROW(B,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(MONTH(B)=MONTH(x))))),D,VLOOKUP(B,A3:B5,2),VSTACK(A2:B2,HSTACK(B,FLOOR(D/C,1)+TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(TAKE(UNIQUE(HSTACK(MONTH(B),RIGHT("0|0|0|0|0|"&REPT("1|",MOD(D,C)),C*2))),,-1)),,"|",1))))
```

Or (just as verbose, but no `TEXTSPLIT()`):

```
=LET(A,SEQUENCE(EOMONTH(A5,0)-A3,,A3),B,FILTER(A,(WEEKDAY(A)=5)*((DAY(A)/7)-0.1<VLOOKUP(A,A3:B5,2))),C,BYROW(B,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(MONTH(B)=MONTH(x))))),D,VLOOKUP(B,A3:B5,2),VSTACK(A2:B2,HSTACK(B,FLOOR(D/C,1)+MID(CONCAT(TAKE(UNIQUE(HSTACK(MONTH(B),RIGHT("00000"&REPT("1",MOD(D,C)),C))),,-1)),SEQUENCE(COUNT(B)),1))))
```

As you can tell, this is a stretch (only proving @Scott's point in the comment that this may be easier through VBA).

---

If you have ms365 but no access to the BETA-functions, you can use:

```
=LET(A,SEQUENCE(EOMONTH(A5,0)-A3,,A3),B,FILTER(A,(WEEKDAY(A)=5)*((DAY(A)/7)-0.1<VLOOKUP(A,A3:B5,2))),C,BYROW(B,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(MONTH(B)=MONTH(x))))),D,VLOOKUP(B,A3:B5,2),CHOOSE({1,2},B,FLOOR(D/C,1)+MID(CONCAT(INDEX(UNIQUE(CHOOSE({1,2},MONTH(B),RIGHT("00000"&REPT("1",MOD(D,C)),C))),,2)),SEQUENCE(COUNT(B)),1)))
```

You'd just need to add titles yourself (since there is no `VSTACK()`).

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Absolutely stunning, +1!

Comment: You definitely needed to put more thought into it than a udf would take. But impressive.

Comment: @ScottCraner absolutely! Took me a while (and a bit longer).

Comment: In case anyone is interested :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72221724/distributing-values-over-time-part-ii